# SWF tag and stage size in preloader code

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

I'm trying to get SWFs frame size from preloader code. Please take a look at the example:

```
[SWF(width='640',height='480',backgroundColor='0xFF00FF',frameRate='60')]
[Frame(factoryClass="MyPreloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    //My main class, which handles the "Application logic"
}

public class MyPreloader extends MovieClip 
{
    //My preloader code - how to get SWF width from here?
}
```

When I compile and embed this into HTML page, I get SWF with proper size - 640x480 with pink color. So "[SWF..]" was interpreted correctly. So is "[Frame..]", because preloader code is running.

I can't get SWF size from preloader code (either from the constructor or in Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event callback method). So far I've tried:

- this.stage.width (returned 0)
- this.stage.loaderInfo.width (got error #2099)
- this.width (returned 0)

Is there any other way getting SWF size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [stage.stageWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stageWidth) and [stage.stageHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stageHeight). Of course after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, but you already did that.

The 'stage.width' property returns the width of the content on the stage and since there is probably nothing on there yet it returns 0.